# Why does an array, when output in raw for come out as gibberish?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I know how ot output an array as a string using Arrays.toString().  But then I have to set the method to return as a string.

a) how come when I run this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  print(myMethod(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4}));
}

public static int[] myMethod(int[] nums){
    return nums;
}
```

I get [I@35a8767  ?

I'd like to know what the compiler is doing in the background when it spits that out.

and

b)  is there a way to have it output correctly without having to make the method return as a String?

Comment: a) You're printing the address of the array in memory. b) Yes, program properly.

Comment: the issue is that "correct" doesn't mean "print the contents of the array"

Comment: Because that's the default form for Object.toString.

Comment: Hint:  Look at the methods of java.util.Arrays.

Comment: a) You're using the default `toString()` implementation of the `Object` class.
b) Try: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));`

Comment: @orlandocr:  I already use use System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));  That was my question.  Is there a way to output it as an int[] instead of as a string without having it print garble?

Comment: @Hot Licks:  am i missing something?  The first line of my original post says that i know how to output using Arrays.toString(). I want to know if I can create a method that is supposed to return int[] and output the array legibly. Or do I have to use Arrays.toString()?

Comment: Yes, you're missing the fact that when you do println on an object there is an implicit call to toString that occurs.  So what you see printed is the toString of an int array.

Comment: @Hot Licks:  never mind.  I got it.  You meant when I print the method from main().  I read too quickly.  Thanks.  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myMethod(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4}))); does the trick.  But bottom line... there's not way to output an array in raw form without looping through each index of the array, correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "raw form".  The "raw form" of an int array is pretty much random (to the eye) bits and bytes.  It must be somehow formatted to be visually meaningful.  Arrays.toString is one way to do that.  The other is to do it yourself.  Those are your options.

Comment: @Hot Licks:  sorry. by "raw form" i mean without having to output it as a string.  I guess the more I learn the more I realize there's no such thing as a legible version of an array.  So I think I'm answering my own question.  Ultimately, to see an array it has to be converted to a string, correct?

Comment: Correct.  You can accept what `toString` returns (just data type and a sort of address), or you can accept what Arrays does, or you can write your own.